# How to replace cell value based on a value in another column for status update?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I was trying to update the status of dozens of items everyday. There are two separate lists, one is for the current status, another is for the items to be updated.

Will there be a way to update the status in one column by referencing the item name in the second list? The item will change from "In progress" to either "completed" or "rejected".

'

picture of lists:
[image: picture of lists]

Comment: `INDEX()` + `MATCH()`, `FILTER()` or even `VLOOKUP` or `XLOOKUP` or... there is tons of ways

Comment: sounds like a job for `vba` rather. please confirm what event will trigger the update?

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

will need more information, for a simple formula it could be if you enter one list, second gets updated, but since formula would be there you can only update one list.

else vba would be needed.

criteria sorting wont be an issue, only issue what i see that either of the list will get auto update. one for inputing , second looking up values from the first list